# How to get values of all the occurence of same element in XSLT?

Tags: xslt

I have an XML File like :

```
<company>
  <dept>
    <name> Dept-A</name>
    <proj> 
      <id> A1 </id>
      <noOfPeople> 5 </noOfPeople>
      <proj> 
        <id>A11</id>
        <noOfPeople> 2 </noOfPeople>
      </proj>
    </proj>
  </dept>
  <dept>
      ....
  </dept>
</company>
```

Now:

1. I want to have a list of all the projects. Even if they are Sub Projects like A11 inside A1, I want every distinct proj id.
2. Also, I want to have this list available to me at multiple locations, Ex. While parsing project A1, or while parsing A11 or any other nesting level of proj.

Is there any way of achieving this in XSLT?

Thank You.
Tara Singh

Comment: @Tara-Singh: Good question (+1). See my answer for two different, complete and short XSLT 1.0 solutions. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. I want to have a list of all the projects. Even if they are Sub
>      Projects like A11 inside A1, I want
>      every distinct proj id.
> 2. Also, I want to have this list available to me at multiple locations,
>      Ex. While parsing project A1, or while
>      parsing A11 or any other nesting level
>      of proj.
>
> Is there any way of achieving this in
>   XSLT?

You haven't specified whether it is possible to have more than one `<proj>` element with the same value of its child `<id>`.

**Here is an XSLT solution that defines two global variables**, one the node-set of all `<id>` elements in the XML document, the other -- a node-set of `<id>` elements each of which has a value that is different from the values of the rest and all values of `<id>`s are sepresented.

As these are *global* variables, they are accessible at any point of your XSLT code, even in imported/included or importing/including stylesheets.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:key name="kIdByVal" match="id" use="."/>

 <xsl:variable name="vallProjIds" select="//proj/id"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vdistinctProjIds" select=
  "//proj/id[generate-id()
            =
             generate-id(key('kIdByVal', .)[1])
            ]
  "/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  All Project IDs:
  <xsl:for-each select="$vallProjIds">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,'&#xA;')"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
  All Distinct Project IDs:
  <xsl:for-each select="$vdistinctProjIds">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,'&#xA;')"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document** (based on the provided one, but made well-formed and extended to cover more cases):

```
<company>
  <dept>
    <name> Dept-A</name>
    <proj>
      <id> A1 </id>
      <noOfPeople> 5 </noOfPeople>
      <proj>
        <id>A11</id>
        <noOfPeople> 2 </noOfPeople>
      </proj>
    </proj>
  </dept>
  <dept>
    <name> Dept-B</name>
    <proj>
      <id> A1 </id>
      <noOfPeople> 5 </noOfPeople>
    </proj>
    <proj>
      <id> B1 </id>
      <noOfPeople> 5 </noOfPeople>
      <proj>
        <id>B11</id>
        <noOfPeople> 2 </noOfPeople>
      </proj>
    </proj>
  </dept>
</company>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
  All Project IDs:
   A1 
   A11
   A1 
   B1 
   B11

  All Distinct Project IDs:
   A1 
   A11
   B1 
   B11
```

**Do note** that this solution uses the Muenchian method for grouping in order to obtain the set of `Id` s with unique values.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible.

The following XPath expression will select all `proj` elements in the document:

```
//proj
```